# RPM require itself

Tags: rpmbuild, rpm-spec

I configure a spec file to build RPM file that requires its base package.
First spec RPM config:

```
%global _installDir  /opt
%global _name        ovcore
%global _build       1
%global _version     1.2.1.R01
%global _release     1

Summary:      First RPM Version
Name:         %{_name}
Version:      %{_version}.%{_build}
Release:      %{_release}
License:      Free.
Group:        OV
URL:          http://free-core.vn
BuildRoot:    %{_tmppath}/%{_name}
Provides:     %{_name} = %{version}-%{release}
```

Then I do an update on my SPEC when building the second:

```
%global _installDir  /opt
%global _name        ovcore
%global _build       10
%global _version     1.2.1.R01
%global _release     1

Summary:      Second RPM Version
Name:         %{_name}
Version:      %{_version}.%{_build}
Release:      %{_release}
License:      Free.
Group:        OV
URL:          http://free-core.vn
BuildRoot:    %{_tmppath}/%{_name}
Provides:     %{_name} = %{version}-%{release}
Requires:     %{_name} = 1.2.1.R01.1-1
```

In my CentOS (7) client, I got this error when installing the second rpm file execute this command:

```
[root@localhost ~]# yum install --debuglevel=10 --rpmverbosity=10  ovcore
install ovcore
Loading "fastestmirror" plugin
Config time: 0.007
Yum version: 3.4.3
rpmdb time: 0.000
Setting up Package Sacks
local                                                                                                                                                | 2.9 kB  00:00:00
local/x86_64/primary_db                                                                                                                              | 1.9 kB  00:00:00
Determining fastest mirrors
pkgsack time: 0.058
Checking for virtual provide or file-provide for install
No package install available.
Obs Init time: 0.000
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package ovcore.x86_64 0:1.2.1.R01.10-1 will be installed
Checking deps for ovcore.x86_64 0:1.2.1.R01.10-1 - u
looking for ('ovcore', 'EQ', ('0', '1.2.1.R01.1', '1')) as a requirement of ovcore.x86_64 0:1.2.1.R01.10-1 - u
looking for ('/bin/sh', None, (None, None, None)) as a requirement of ovcore.x86_64 0:1.2.1.R01.10-1 - u
looking for ('/bin/sh', None, (None, None, None)) as a requirement of ovcore.x86_64 0:1.2.1.R01.10-1 - u
ovcore-1.2.1.R01.10-1.x86_64 requires: ovcore = 1.2.1.R01.1-1
--> Processing Dependency: ovcore = 1.2.1.R01.1-1 for package: ovcore-1.2.1.R01.10-1.x86_64
Searching pkgSack for dep: ovcore
Potential resolving package ovcore-1.2.1.R01.1-1.x86_64 has newer instance in ts.
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Dependency Process ending
Depsolve time: 0.385
Error: Package: ovcore-1.2.1.R01.10-1.x86_64 (local)
           Requires: ovcore = 1.2.1.R01.1-1
           Available: ovcore-1.2.1.R01.1-1.x86_64 (local)
               ovcore = 1.2.1.R01.1-1
               ovcore = 1.2.1.R01-1
           Installing: ovcore-1.2.1.R01.10-1.x86_64 (local)
               ovcore = 1.2.1.R01.10-1
               ovcore = 1.2.1.R01-1
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
[root@localhost ~]#
```

The main idea in here is:

If someone installed my RPM file on their system. On later if my program has a bug, then i need to create a patch to fix it (This patch should be target for 1 build only). This mean, I need to create the patch RPM file to upload to repository.
Then, in the client PC, they can perform "yum update ovcore" to apply my patch fix.

Appreciate for any help!

Answer (score 0):

`1.2.1.R01.10-1` (version installing) != `1.2.1.R01.1-1` (explicitly required in the second spec). Why are you saying it requires an old version of itself at all?

Other misc notes:

- Build numbers should probably go in the release field unless you are the original author of the program being packaged as well.
- You shouldn't make your variables start with `_` because you might accidentally stomp internal ones.

Comment: Thanks Aaron for your comments, I have updated the logs. Pls check it. Yes, I'm the oringinal author of the program ovcore.

Comment: My answer still applies. The second one should *not* require the first. RPM is not for live patching. The next version of your RPM will totally replace the previous.